# How can I decompile native within C#

Tags: c#, native, reverse-engineering

I was doing research on a program (executable).  I decompiled the program using ILSpy.  While I reviewed the source code, I discovered a function that looked like this:

```
/ <Module>
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged | MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]    
internal unsafe static extern PointerObject* Function(sbyte*);
```

There was no implementation.  How can I disassemble this?

Answer (score 1):

A method with the `extern` keyword means that the implementation of that method is specified in some external file. You can read more about `extern` in the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx). Normally you would see a `DLLImportAttribute` which would specify the name of the assembly that the method is implemented in.

`MethodImpOptions.Unmanaged` implies that the call is being made to unmanaged code (C, C++, etc) and `MethodImpOptions.PreserveSig` means that the method being called has the exact same method signature.

Beyond that, I can't tell you much.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a native call, you need a native disassembler. There's plenty to choose from with wildly different level of output, but you'll most likely need a good understanding of x86 assembly and Windows programming to get anythig useful from the disassembly - it's nothing like disassembled C# code, for example.

The native code might be in a separate DLL, or in a native module in the same assembly - you'll need to check where that `extern` definition is pointing.

*Disclaimer: disassembly and/or using any knowledge obtained in this way may be illegal where you are; make sure you're aware of the applicable laws.*